# Setup default view the current day for apexcharts rangeBar chart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am using [apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/) library. So far looks very promising.
I have a requirement to have a default zoom on the current day.
Is that possible? I have search the documentation but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had to call `zoomX` after rendering.

```
chart.render();
chart.zoomX(this.startOfDay(), this.endOfDay())
```